# Lookup for documents and return only the missing values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

I have 2 collections like that, being `A` a 1.5kk documents collection:

```
A
_id
relation: { alias, ref: 'B/<_id>' }

B
_id
name
```

I want to query for the elements in `A`, that aren't in `B`. This is what I get so far:

```
db.getCollection('A').aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            'relation.ref': {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                    { $split: ['$relation.ref', '/'] }, 1
                ]
            },
            a: "$$ROOT"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'B',
            localField: 'relation.ref',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'b'
        }
    }
]);
```

This does return things in this pattern:

```
{
  _id,
  relation.ref,
  a: {},
  b: [{}]
}
```

Well I was expecting to add a $match clause to include only the ones with b being an empty array. Something like `${match: { b: {$size: 0} } }`

The problem is that this query seems to take too long. I never saw it working, thus I dont know it is the right way.

Is there anything to make it perform better or a different way to get this?

For example, if I force a wrong join, it will return an empty array on `b`. But querying the size of this array is always slow, even when I query for `{$size: 1}`, that is 99,9% of the results. I wonder if i could do something like this to select only the missing values during the join:

`{$lookup.pipeline: [{$myself: null}] }`

Ideas, please?

Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Your `$match` syntax was close but a little off, you should use something like this:

```
{
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          0,
          {
            $size: "$b"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xyFrww3VQuL)

However wouldn't it be easier to update the `relation` field to only contain valid refs? and if that's the case you can just query `'relation.ref': {$exists: false}`

Comment: Hey, tom, where should I use the `'relation.ref': {$exists: false}`? In the projection statement? The `$match` expression, where are you putting it? In the `$lookup.pipeline`? It wont allow me, because it says you can`t pass `foreignField` and `localField` alongside `pipeline`. But `b` only exists after the join

Comment: if I put the expression you sent me in the outer $match, same lavel as `project` and `lookup` it takes too long. after 200 seconds it hangs up. should I change the timeout?

Comment: `$lookup` is a really expensive operation for Mongo and it's usually not recommended on using it. that's why i suggested on the alternative which is updating the `relation` field ahead of time and then you can know which documents are relevant without the `$lookup`.